# HTML 5 Canvas Whiteboard for iOS

Tags: ios, html, canvas

I have been working with the code here: http://code.google.com/p/html-5-canvas-whiteboard/

Everything works great in the browser, but not on iOS devices.

Can anyone point me in the right direction to make this iOS compatible? More specifically, I would like it to work in Safari for my iPad.

Here is a test version of my code: http://www.coderedsupport.com/whiteboard

Any advice would be great.

Comment: You should use the [W3C Touch Events API](https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/webevents/raw-file/tip/touchevents.html). Also see https://github.com/katspaugh/whiteboard for sample code.

Answer (score 3):

You have `mousedown`, `mouseup`, and `mousemove` events, you need to add `touchstart`, `touchend` and `touchmove` events to match them.

Comment: I am really hitting a wall on this.  Are you aware of any sample code I can use?  I know that is lazy, but I have no choice.

Answer (score 1):

You need to map the mouse-click events used for drawing on the whiteboard to actual touch-events. Just have a look in the [Apple-Developer-Libraries](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/appleapplications/reference/safariwebcontent/handlingevents/handlingevents.html) I used it for a little proof-of-concept and it worked just fine with iOS and Android.

**UPDATE:** Regarding to your comment, you should have a look at this [Blog](http://backtothecode.blogspot.com/2009/10/javascript-touch-and-gesture-events.html)